# Getting a working visa in time for Christmas

Tags: visas, australia, working-holiday

I am a British citizen currently in Australia for the next few weeks.
I am after changing to a working holiday visa by flying up to Bali and sorting it - so I can work here until the end of February.

I was curious is there and possibility that I will be able to be granted one even though my passport expires in August 2018? 
I will apply for a new passport ASAP but I really want to be back in Brisbane by Christmas week.
I am willing to pay any perhaps fast track service that could sort this out with speed.

Comment: Please split this into several questions - one about passport validity for working holiday visas and one about processing times.